# VBA create loop for column B based on value in column A

Tags: loops, excel, if-statement, vba

I have a code that does what I need. The problem is I have to do the range select manually I'd like to create a conditional loop.

Here's my code that I used so far

```
Sub Worksheet_functions()
    Dim Sumtotal As Long
    Sumtotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)
    Range("e2").Value = Sumtotal
    Range("h2").Value = Range("e2") + Range("h2")
End Sub
```

This is what my data looks like

```
         Price Volume     E   H
          10    100
          10    50
          10    80
          9     100
          9     50
          8     100
          8     100
          10    50
          10    250
```

At the moment I'm manually selection the volume column from the top down based on the value in price column.

The conditions are

1. If The prices are the same continue selecting them until they are not
2. If the price goes down then those selected cells should be summed in e4 and added to h4
3. If the price goes up then those selected cells should be summed in e2 and added to h4

For my example this would look like:

```
              ( H2: 100+50+80  +50+250 = 530 )
              ( H4: 100+50  +100+100   = 350 )

               Price Volume     
               ( 10    100               
   100+50+80 < ( 10    50                
               ( 10    80
           Above volume to H2
                (9     100               
     100+50   < (9     50
           Above volume to H4 ( because 10>9)
                (8     100
      100+100 < (8     100
            Above volume to H4 ( because 9>8)    
                (10    50
       50+250 < (10    250              
             Above volume to H2 ( because 8<10)
```

Any suggestions on

1. How do I use the conditions to make it loop?
2. How do write a code that takes in consideration the last price?

Comment: the way you describe it, it will just be `Summed` in H4. or am i missing something. your illustration of expected result is vague as well. please elaborate.

Comment: Yes the overall sum of whewn the price went down is in H4, and the overall sum of whent the price went up is in H2.

I will edit the expected result to try and make it more clear

Comment: ah so it must be `H4: 100+50+80, 100+50, 100+100` then `H2: 50+250` right?

Comment: ok i get. working on your possible code now... :)

Comment: See the volume as blocks. The first 3 blocks goes in to H2. Then price changes to 9. 9 is smaller then 10 therefore the blocks of 9's goes into H4. 8 is smaller then 9 therefhore the blocks of 8's goes into H4. 10 is bigger then 8 therefore the blocks of 10's goes into H2.

I know I need some for loop and if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to get what you want.
It is much difficult to create `loop` and `Nested If's` to do this.
I let `Excel` do the job and used `Formula` instead.

Let say your data is in `A1:B10`.

In `E2` type this in formula bar.

```
=IF(A2=A3,IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1<A2,1,IF(A1=A2,E1,0)),1),IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1<A2,1,IF(A1=A2,E1,0)),1))
```

Copy the formula all the way down until `E10` or up to where you have data.

In `H2`, type this in formula bar:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,1,B:B)
```

Similarly in `H4`, type this in formula bar:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,0,B:B)
```

However, you want code in VBA which is below also using above formula:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet, lrow as long

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")'assuming your data is in Sheet1

With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E2:E" & lrow).Formula = "=IF(A2=A3,IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1<A2,1,IF(A1=A2,E1,0)),1),IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1<A2,1,IF(A1=A2,E1,0)),1))"
    .Range("E2:E" & lrow).Value = .Range("E2:E" & lrow).Value
    .Range("H2").Formula = "=SUMIF(E:E,1,B:B)"
    .Range("H2").Value = .Range("H2").Value
    .Range("H4").Formula = "=SUMIF(E:E,0,B:B)"
    .Range("H4").Value = .Range("H4").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Kinda late, but I hope this is what you want.

Comment: I know how difficult this code was to figure out and especially my "demands" which was unclear and hard to define. But you did it and it's doing what I what it to do. I've been struggling with this for weeks trying to figure out different solutions that makes it more simple, so that even though I'm not so good in VBA I'd be able to write it anyways. But nothing has worked so far. I've been so frustrated and I can't thank you enough!  "L42" Thank you for giving your time and effort to help me! And thanks to stackoverflow for being an amazing website.

Comment: you are very welcome. I also learned a lot of things from the VBA Gurus here who are very generous of their time. I am only living to their set example to help out others best way I can. glad it helped you.

Comment: btw, you can further simplify the formula above to this formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1<A2,1,IF(A1=A2,E1,0)),1)`. I just figured now while reviewing it. :)